# How do I use chrome inspect with a react native application on a device?

Tags: google-chrome, react-native

I have an application with a webview that I need to inspect. I can't see it when I goto `chrome://inspect/`. Everything I'm reading says it should just show up.

The device is an Amazon FireTV Stick Gen 2.

I'm building and running it on the device with `react-native run-android --configuration Debug`. When I run `react-native log-android`, i see:

```
Starting the logger (/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V)...
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of metrics
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of amazon_main
--------- beginning of vitals
--------- beginning of kernel
--------- beginning of main
I/ReactNativeJS( 7798): Running application "sagelySignApp" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON
```

In chrome I see:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for remote debugging instead of logs from the actual device. You can take a look at react's [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#chrome-developer-tools) about debugging using chrome developer tools.